# tiny_mce insert/edit image custom html

Tags: html, image, tinymce

How to change html output when inserting image

from this:

```
<img title="?" src="?" alt="?" width="xxx" height="xxx" />
```

into this:

```
<a href="?" rel="?" title="?"> <img src="?" alt="?"></a>
```

How to set variables.

Answer (score 2):

Found answer by my own.
I edited tiny_mce\plugins\advimage\js\image.js

```
ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, tinyMCEPopup.editor.dom.createHTML('img', args), {skip_undo : 1});
```

into

```
ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, tinyMCEPopup.editor.dom.setHTML(tinyMCE.activeEditor.dom, '<a href="'+ foo +'" rel="lightbox[article]" title="'+ args['title'] +'"> <img src="'+ args['src'] +'" alt="'+ args['title'] +'"></a>'), {skip_undo : 1});
```